# How to list all files in a directory and its subdirectories in hadoop hdfs

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have a folder in hdfs which has two subfolders each one has about 30 subfolders which,finally,each one contains xml files.
I want to list all xml files giving only the main folder's path.
Locally I can do this with [apache commons-io's](http://commons.apache.org/io/) FileUtils.listFiles().
I have tried this

```
FileStatus[] status = fs.listStatus( new Path( args[ 0 ] ) );
```

but it only lists the two first subfolders and it doesn't go further.
Is there any way to do this in hadoop?

Comment: I know this is a java-oriented question but if others reading have the option to use operating system commands, `hadoop fs -ls -R /user/your_directory` should recursively list directories

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You'll need to use the [FileSystem](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) object and perform some logic on the resultant FileStatus objects to manually recurse into the subdirectories.

You can also apply a PathFilter to only return the xml files using the [listStatus(Path, PathFilter)](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#listStatus%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.PathFilter%29) method

The hadoop FsShell class has examples of this for the hadoop fs -lsr command, which is a recursive ls - see [the source](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/tags/release-1.0.3/src/core/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FsShell.java?view=markup), around line 590 (the recursive step is triggered on line 635)

Comment: Finally I did a simpler implementation than the one you suggest but you gave me the idea.Thanx!!!

Comment: broken reference links

Comment: @nik686 can you please provide the solution you applied

Comment: I found that FileSystem fs = path.getFileSystem(conf); instead of FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf) correctly loads the fs type (hdfs://, gs://...) otherwise I got java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS ... expected: file:///

Answer (score 34):

If you are using hadoop 2.* API there are more elegant solutions:

```
    Configuration conf = getConf();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

    //the second boolean parameter here sets the recursion to true
    RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> fileStatusListIterator = fs.listFiles(
            new Path("path/to/lib"), true);
    while(fileStatusListIterator.hasNext()){
        LocatedFileStatus fileStatus = fileStatusListIterator.next();
        //do stuff with the file like ...
        job.addFileToClassPath(fileStatus.getPath());
    }
```

Comment: what is the getConf() method?

Comment: `getConf()` is a method in the `Configured` class. Your class would ideally extend this.

Comment: I found that `FileSystem fs = path.getFileSystem(conf);` instead of `FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf)` correctly loads the fs type (hdfs://, gs://...) otherwise I got `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS ... expected: file:///`.

Answer (score 17):

```
/**
 * @param filePath
 * @param fs
 * @return list of absolute file path present in given path
 * @throws FileNotFoundException
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static List<String> getAllFilePath(Path filePath, FileSystem fs) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
    FileStatus[] fileStatus = fs.listStatus(filePath);
    for (FileStatus fileStat : fileStatus) {
        if (fileStat.isDirectory()) {
            fileList.addAll(getAllFilePath(fileStat.getPath(), fs));
        } else {
            fileList.add(fileStat.getPath().toString());
        }
    }
    return fileList;
}
```

Quick Example : Suppose you have the following file structure:

```
a  ->  b
   ->  c  -> d
          -> e 
   ->  d  -> f
```

Using the code above, you get:

```
a/b
a/c/d
a/c/e
a/d/f
```

If you want only the leaf (i.e. fileNames), use the following code in `else` block :

```
 ...
    } else {
        String fileName = fileStat.getPath().toString(); 
        fileList.add(fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
    }
```

This will give:

```
b
d
e
f
```

Comment: `fileStat.getPath().toString()` result format `hdfs://nameservice1/knime/1/2e4a7753-ce62-4ab1-85a1-7dc4e7aae3d5.xlsx` start with hdfs://

Comment: I found that FileSystem fs = path.getFileSystem(conf); instead of FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf) correctly loads the fs type (hdfs://, gs://...) otherwise I got java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS ... expected: file:///

Answer (score 14):

Have you tried this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

public class cat{
    public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception{
        try{
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
            FileStatus[] status = fs.listStatus(new Path("hdfs://test.com:9000/user/test/in"));  // you need to pass in your hdfs path

            for (int i=0;i<status.length;i++){
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(status[i].getPath())));
                String line;
                line=br.readLine();
                while (line != null){
                    System.out.println(line);
                    line=br.readLine();
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I have seen the same example,I ve referred to this above.But it lists the subdirectories in depth 1.I want to get in the final files from the main folder

Answer (score 3):

Now, one can use Spark to do the same and its way faster than other approaches (such as Hadoop MR). Here is the code snippet.

```
def traverseDirectory(filePath:String,recursiveTraverse:Boolean,filePaths:ListBuffer[String]) {
    val files = FileSystem.get( sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration ).listStatus(new Path(filePath))
            files.foreach { fileStatus => {
                if(!fileStatus.isDirectory() && fileStatus.getPath().getName().endsWith(".xml")) {                
                    filePaths+=fileStatus.getPath().toString()      
                }
                else if(fileStatus.isDirectory()) {
                    traverseDirectory(fileStatus.getPath().toString(), recursiveTraverse, filePaths)
                }
            }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Code snippet for both recursive and non-recursive approaches:

```
//helper method to get the list of files from the HDFS path
public static List<String>
    listFilesFromHDFSPath(Configuration hadoopConfiguration,
                          String hdfsPath,
                          boolean recursive) throws IOException,
                                        IllegalArgumentException
{
    //resulting list of files
    List<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();

    //get path from string and then the filesystem
    Path path = new Path(hdfsPath);  //throws IllegalArgumentException
    FileSystem fs = path.getFileSystem(hadoopConfiguration);

    //if recursive approach is requested
    if(recursive)
    {
        //(heap issues with recursive approach) => using a queue
        Queue<Path> fileQueue = new LinkedList<Path>();

        //add the obtained path to the queue
        fileQueue.add(path);

        //while the fileQueue is not empty
        while (!fileQueue.isEmpty())
        {
            //get the file path from queue
            Path filePath = fileQueue.remove();

            //filePath refers to a file
            if (fs.isFile(filePath))
            {
                filePaths.add(filePath.toString());
            }
            else   //else filePath refers to a directory
            {
                //list paths in the directory and add to the queue
                FileStatus[] fileStatuses = fs.listStatus(filePath);
                for (FileStatus fileStatus : fileStatuses)
                {
                    fileQueue.add(fileStatus.getPath());
                } // for
            } // else

        } // while

    } // if
    else        //non-recursive approach => no heap overhead
    {
        //if the given hdfsPath is actually directory
        if(fs.isDirectory(path))
        {
            FileStatus[] fileStatuses = fs.listStatus(path);

            //loop all file statuses
            for(FileStatus fileStatus : fileStatuses)
            {
                //if the given status is a file, then update the resulting list
                if(fileStatus.isFile())
                    filePaths.add(fileStatus.getPath().toString());
            } // for
        } // if
        else        //it is a file then
        {
            //return the one and only file path to the resulting list
            filePaths.add(path.toString());
        } // else

    } // else

    //close filesystem; no more operations
    fs.close();

    //return the resulting list
    return filePaths;
} // listFilesFromHDFSPath
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snippet, that counts number of files in a particular HDFS directory (I used this to determine how many reducers to use in a particular ETL code). You can easily modify this to suite your needs.

```
private int calculateNumberOfReducers(String input) throws IOException {
    int numberOfReducers = 0;
    Path inputPath = new Path(input);
    FileSystem fs = inputPath.getFileSystem(getConf());
    FileStatus[] statuses = fs.globStatus(inputPath);
    for(FileStatus status: statuses) {
        if(status.isDirectory()) {
            numberOfReducers += getNumberOfInputFiles(status, fs);
        } else if(status.isFile()) {
            numberOfReducers ++;
        }
    }
    return numberOfReducers;
}

/**
 * Recursively determines number of input files in an HDFS directory
 *
 * @param status instance of FileStatus
 * @param fs instance of FileSystem
 * @return number of input files within particular HDFS directory
 * @throws IOException
 */
private int getNumberOfInputFiles(FileStatus status, FileSystem fs) throws IOException  {
    int inputFileCount = 0;
    if(status.isDirectory()) {
        FileStatus[] files = fs.listStatus(status.getPath());
        for(FileStatus file: files) {
            inputFileCount += getNumberOfInputFiles(file, fs);
        }
    } else {
        inputFileCount ++;
    }

    return inputFileCount;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

don't use recursive approach (heap issues) :)
use a queue

```
queue.add(param_dir)
while (queue is not empty){

  directory=  queue.pop
 - get items from current directory
 - if item is file add to a list (final list)
 - if item is directory => queue.push
}
```

that was easy, enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Radu Adrian Moldovan for the suggestion.

Here is an implementation using queue:

```
private static List<String> listAllFilePath(Path hdfsFilePath, FileSystem fs)
throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
  List<String> filePathList = new ArrayList<String>();
  Queue<Path> fileQueue = new LinkedList<Path>();
  fileQueue.add(hdfsFilePath);
  while (!fileQueue.isEmpty()) {
    Path filePath = fileQueue.remove();
    if (fs.isFile(filePath)) {
      filePathList.add(filePath.toString());
    } else {
      FileStatus[] fileStatus = fs.listStatus(filePath);
      for (FileStatus fileStat : fileStatus) {
        fileQueue.add(fileStat.getPath());
      }
    }
  }
  return filePathList;
}
```