# Search for Files in Hadoop using Python

Tags: python, hadoop

I am trying to search for files that contain a certain prefix in a Hadoop directory. Right now I have this line of code to search locally:

```
onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) ]
```

And I believe I have found a Java equivalent that works for Hadoop from this previous thread: [How to list all files in a directory and its subdirectories in hadoop hdfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342400/how-to-list-all-files-in-a-directory-and-its-subdirectories-in-hadoop-hdfs)

Is there a Python equivalent I can use?

Comment: There is example code of a recursive search using fnmatch at https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html and https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/fnmatch.htm.  Some other examples are in a tutuorial at http://www.pythoncentral.io/recursive-file-and-directory-manipulation-in-python-part-1/

Comment: How does that apply to searching in a Hadoop directory? Right now even though I am operating in a Hadoop environment, when I use any os methods it thinks that I am referring to local paths, not hdfs paths. @TrisNefzger

Comment: It can be done with pywebhdfs, but I would do it the easy way using hadoop fs -ls -R starting_path |awk '{print $8}' | grep "^prefix" > data.out.