# Spark: Traverse HDFS subfolders and find all files with name "X"

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

I have a HDFS path and I want to traverse through all the subfolders and find all the files within that have the name "X".

I have tried to do this:

```
FileSystem.get( sc.hadoopConfiguration )
  .listStatus( new Path("hdfs://..."))
  .foreach( x => println(x.getPath))
```

But this only searches for files within 1 level and I want all levels.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list all files in a directory and its subdirectories in hadoop hdfs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342400/how-to-list-all-files-in-a-directory-and-its-subdirectories-in-hadoop-hdfs)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get all the files recursively. Loop through the path and get all the files, if it is a directory call the same function once again.
Below is a simple code you can modify as your configuration and test.

```
var fileSystem : FileSystem = _
  var configuration: Configuration = _

  def init() {
    configuration = new Configuration
    fileSystem = FileSystem.get(configuration)
    val fileStatus: Array[FileStatus] = fileSystem.listStatus(new Path(""))
    getAllFiles(fileStatus)
  }

  def getAllFiles(fileStatus: Array[FileStatus]) {
    fileStatus.map(fs  => {
      if (fs.isDirectory)
        getAllFiles(fileSystem.listStatus(fs.getPath))
      else fs
    })
  }
```

Also filter the files that contains 'X' after getting the file list.