# How can I access a directory located in HDFS from a Python script?

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

I have a Python script that walks over all the files in a directory and prints metadata such as filename, extension, size, creation_time, etc.

The problem is that I want to pass as input a directory located in HDFS.
I don't know how to approach this.

I tried a lot of stuff like hdfs3, pywebhdfs, snakebite, and so on. 
But mainly these extensions offer basic HDFS command and I don't know how to access the folder located in HDFS.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(MyDirectory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(MyExtension):
            #get File Name
            a = (os.path.join(root, file))
            #print a
            filename = a
            MyFileName = basename(a)

            #get File Size
            MyFileSize = getSize(filename) / 1000
            print MyFileName + " >>> file size: " + str(MyFileSize) + "Kb"
```

In the os.walk(MyDirectory) should be the location of the directory from hdfs, in my case: hdfs://quickstar.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/directory

Comment: Short answer: there isn't an easy way... Those libraries you tried should have a way of listing contents of a directory, but without using just giving up and using the Java API, getting the information you want probably won't be available from Python libraries (unless you dig into libhdfs C bindings)

Comment: Thank you @cricket_007. I invested one more day to research this, but I think I will go with Java.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342400/how-to-list-all-files-in-a-directory-and-its-subdirectories-in-hadoop-hdfs