# How to find if the file exists in hdfs using Java?

Tags: java, maven, hdfs, hadoop2

I am trying to find if the trigger files exist in the hdfs directory.

Code:

```
    private static final int index = 23;
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private static HashMap<String, Boolean> files = new HashMap<String, Boolean>() {{
        put("/user/ct_troy/allfiles/_TRIG1", false);
        put("/user/ct_troy/allfiles/_TRIG2", false);
        put("/user/ct_troy/allfiles/_TRIG3", false);
        put("/user/ct_troy/allfiles/_TRIG4", false);
        put("/user/ct_troy/allfiles/_TRIG5", false);
    }};

    private static boolean availableFiles(String file_name){
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
        config.set("fs.file.impl", org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());
        try {
            FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(config);
            // Hadoop DFS Path - Input file
            Path path = new Path(file_name); // file_name - complete path and file name.
            // Check if input is valid
            if (hdfs.exists(path) == false) {
                System.out.println(file_name + " not found.");
                throw new FileNotFoundException(file_name.substring(index));
            }
            else{
                    System.out.println(file_name + " File Present.");
                    return true;
                }
            }catch (IOException e) {
            }
        return false;
    }
```

I am passing keys of `HashMap<> files` as `file_name` argument to function `availableFiles`.
I built a jar and ran it on the node, it gave me the following output:

```
_TRIG2 not found.
_TRIG3 not found.
_TRIG1 not found.
_TRIG4 not found.
_TRIG5 not found.
```

Not sure why this is happening, `_TRIG1`, `_TRIG2` and `_TRIG3` exist, where as `_TRIG4` and `_TRIG5` don't. It's giving me the same result for all the trigger files. Help.

Comment: Hello, maybe you can follow that : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25645225/390462

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation, you can check if the files you need exists with a direct internal call : @see https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#test

```
test

Usage: hadoop fs -test -[defswrz] URI

Options:

    -d: f the path is a directory, return 0.
    -e: if the path exists, return 0.
    -f: if the path is a file, return 0.
    -s: if the path is not empty, return 0.
    -w: if the path exists and write permission is granted, return 0.
    -r: if the path exists and read permission is granted, return 0.
    -z: if the file is zero length, return 0.

Example:

    hadoop fs -test -e filename
```

Your java code seems to look good. Maybe your if test is not well wrotten :

```
if (!hdfs.exists(path)) { // <=================== @see the change and test it.
```